# Is mutex compatible with pthread in C++11?

Tags: c++11, pthreads, mutex

Despite `pthread_mutex`, would mutex (`#include <mutex>`) make pthread safe using C++11?

Please find down an example:

```
// Creating Server thread
pthread_create(&server_thread, NULL,Server,NULL);

// Creating Client thread
pthread_create(&client_thread, NULL, Client,NULL);

// Wait until client_thread exits
pthread_join( client_thread, NULL);
```

both Server, and Client call `foo()`.

```
mutex mut;
void foo (){
     mut.lock();
     CRITICAL_WRITE();
     mut.unlock();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "compatible with pthread?" Is it likely that your C++ standard library, when running on a system with pthreads support, uses that as a backend for `<mutex>`? Yes. Is that guaranteed? I suppose not, but you can always try looking at the standard library source code directly.

Comment: @Moi Still, "compatibility" is ambiguous. There are two questions that fit. Can you use `pthreads` and stdc++ threads in one program? And can you interchange them? Like `new/delete` and `malloc/free`. You can you them in one program safely. Can you freely interchange calls for their counter parts? Nope. I think in your case you can use both, but I won't bet anything where you can mix them between concepts. Though, I think is should be easy enough to write a simple test. You got like 50% of code already.

Comment: @luk32, I edited the question again.

Comment: please do not manually lock and unlock an `std::mutex` use [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) to do it. Manually locking and unlocking risks deadlock on an exception. Also you can always use [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is implementation specific. The C++11 standard libraries I know about (e.g. `libstdc++` in  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) 4.9, and probably also `libc++` from [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)) are practically built above the existing [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) library on Linux.

Someone could in principle build some C++11 standard library on Linux directly using [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (e.g. [futex(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html) -mixed with hand-written assembly code- for mutual exclusion locks), but I know none such C++11 library.

The threads are built on Linux in pthreads above the low-level [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) syscall.

So you don't have a formal guarantee, but in practice you are *today* quite safe (on Linux)